# PHP - create email source and send "as is"

Tags: php, email, smtp

I created an email "as source", meaning that the headers, boundaries, body and so on are stored in a string (just how a spool email looks). How can I send this email via PHP?

Thank you!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: I wrote the headers, boundaries, body "by hand". I don't need to "add body, subject, to, from..." since they are *in* the email that I created as source. I just need to send it as it is.